# Collect with symbolic exponents

Tags: symbolic

I need to collect a polynomial in a variable `r`. The exponents of `r` are possbily symbolic.
For example, the expression

```
Collect[r^(2 a) (1 + r^2) + (1 + a) r^2, r]
```

gives

```
r^(2 a) + r^2 (1 + a + r^(2 a))
```

while what I would like to have is

```
r^(2 a) + r^2 (1 + a) + r^(2+2 a)
```

Of course my expression is much more complicated, but this gives the idea of what happens.

Comment: What about Expand insted of Collect?

Comment: @FredSimons I want all the terms that are multiplied by the same power of r to stay together. Expand would not work in this case. I will change the example to make it clearer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example with some extra terms:

```
exp=r^(2 a)+r^2 (1+a+r^(2 a)) + r + a r;
```

`Collect` accepts patterns, so you can collect with respect to powers of `r`:

```
Collect[exp, r^_]
(* (1+a) r+(1+a) r^2+r^(2 a)+r^(2+2 a) *)
```